# how to stop running app before timeout in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, timeout

I created an Android application in Eclipse.

When I wanted to run it, it stopped due to timeout. So, I increased the ADB connection timeout to a big number! But after running again, it seems that my application has an error and timeout is not the problem.

But the ADB connection timeout is too big for me to wait!

How can I stop running the app before timeout?!

I tried to stop it from the Device pan but that doesn't work.

Comment: You testing in emulator or real device?

Comment: What is our current adb connection time out?

Comment: your question is irrelevant! you can suppose timeout is infinite!